# In AWS IOT rules how would I query the metadata to have them show up in the results

Tags: aws-iot

I have tried several different combinations to query for metadata (specifically the timestamp) and have come up blank. The only thing that works is to SELECT * which I don't really want to do. Is it possible to select metadata?

I was hoping for something like

```
SELECT state.metadata.reported as metadata FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'
```

But this doesn't work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a known bug and "will be fixed real soon now" - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=690079&#690079